# Altnerative to Gnash

Tags: ffmpeg, flash, gnash

I am currently using Gnash for its video conversion features - specifically being able to pass it FlashVars (SWF).

However it is old and slow. Is there a newer faster alternative that supports FlashVars?

Answer (score 0):

Shumway is an HTML5 technology experiment that explores building a faithful and efficient renderer for the SWF file format without native code assistance.

[Shumway](http://mozilla.github.io/shumway)

Comment: How would this work though? Gnash can read a SWF file with passed flashvars and output it as a RAW file for later conversion. However it appears that Shumway is only a player. Does it have a command line tool for conversion?